# i received a negative "point" for a question I didn't even ask, answer or comment on! Why would that be?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm referring to this question:  [Who were the Hellenistic and Hebraic Jews of Acts 6:1?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/371/who-were-the-hellenistic-and-hebraic-jews-of-acts-61/20075#20075)

Comment: [Did you down vote an _answer_](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)? That gives you -1 to reputation (and is not related to asking, answering, or commenting on).

Comment: I must have. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Downvoting posts costs the voter one reputation point. This is to discourage frivolous use of the feature among new community participants that are not well established yet.

A complete list of things that affect reputation is [available in the help center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Thanks. That was my first down vote, for which I simultaneously received the "Critic" badge so my stock is doing okay and the investors are satisfied.